# Docx4j.toPDF - hf.fo file

Tags: docx4j

I'm creating a pdf like this:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));
OutputStream os = new java.io.FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);

Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, os);
```

It works fine. 
After the pdf created, a hf.fo file appears in the doot directory. Why? How can I change the path of this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    foSettings.setFoDumpFile(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/hf.fo"));
}
```

Turn off DEBUG level logging for org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.FOPAreaTreeHelper